# Documentation for Python Azure IoTHub SDK

Tags: python, azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

Is there any real documentation for the Python Azure IoTHub SDK?  I have found a few code samples but nothing comprehensive.  It's also hard to correlate with the documentation for other language SDK's as they all seem slightly different.  Even the source code is not good documentation as it's actually a wrapper over C++.

I'd like to be able to take advantage of all the features, but I can't.  For instance in the code samples we see `send_confirmation_callback`, `receive_message_callback`, `device_twin_callback`, `device_method_callback`, and `blob_upload_conf_callback`, and it's not clear to me what these all do, or what other kinds of callbacks there might be.

Am I missing it or does it not exist?

Comment: Please refer to [Microsoft Azure IoT SDKs for Python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/master/readme.md).This document guides you to use the sdk for python.

Comment: I've seen that, and it does offer some pointers, but not what would traditionally be called documentation.  Thanks for pointing it out though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation on Python SDK is indeed a gap.  We are working on better documentation now and I will circle back with an update.

In the meantime, these documentations may be helpful:

1. There are two available tutorials on Python.  [This document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-python-getstarted) walks through send_confirmation_callback and receive_message_callback.  [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-raspberry-pi-kit-python-get-started) is a tutorial for Rasp Pi.
2. Python SDK is a wrapper on our C SDK.  You can take a look at the [C API documentation](https://azure.github.io/azure-iot-sdk-c/index.html).  For example, send_confirmation_callback is SendConfirmationCallback in C.  [This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-device-sdk-c-iothubclient) on the C SDK describes SendConfirmationCallback and ReceiveMessageCallback in great detail.

If you run into any problem, you can open an issue in [our repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out these documents.  I look forward to hearing back when there is documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This is really disappointing that as of July 2019, no documentation/API reference is available for Azure IOT suite's python SDK. What we have is a git repository with uncommented C-code or some sample programs.
To answer your question, No, there is no documentation as of now. I personally had to add dotnet in my stack only to get it working. Though working with python SDK would make life marginally better if there WAS a python SDK. The current one is simply a wrapper on created with BOOST. However, you can look into the API references for dotnet SDK and then moving back to the so-called Python SDK get's relatively easier. 
-Cheers (: